# Net Core: how to separate controllers by ports?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to separate controllers by ports inside netcore2.0 selfhosted web service.

Example:

There are  2 ports(p1 and p2) and 3 controllers(c1, c2, c3). 
Requirement scheme: c1 processes requests from p1, but c2 and c3 will processes requests from p2.

Any ideas about how can i do that?

Comment: The only obvious reason for this would be security (blocking certain ports for certain groups of people, for example inside/outside access), so maybe it's easier to just create two applications, one with C1 and one with C2+C3?

Comment: You are right about security, but it is not variant for me create and support additional service in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got answer on GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8502

```
[PortActionConstraint(5000)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   ...
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PortActionConstraint : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public PortActionConstraint(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
    }

    public int Port { get; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        //external port
        var externalPort = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Port;
        //local port 
        var localPort = routeContext.HttpContext.Connection.LocalPort;
        //write here your custom logic. for example  
        return Port == localPort ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work when running the process behind a proxy. It already even fails in the simple case of docker port mappings. To verify, build a docker image, run it with `-p 4000:5000` and access it via `localhost:4000` and see the 404s logged by your process running on port 5000 internally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. HttpContext.Request.Host.Port is external port. In our solution we using HttpContext.Connection.LocalPort instead of HttpContext.Request.Host.Port and custom IActionFilter instead of custom attribute. it's works ok. I will fix answer